# Libgdx HTML5 AnimationScheduler Length is Null

Tags: javascript, java, gwt, libgdx

I created a libdx game and it works fine in Android and Desktop versions.  In the game, I have a bird the flies around and must avoid other objects.  If it contacts the objects, the game is over and the game over screen appears.

In my GWT Application, the first time the game over screen appears I have no issues, but if I restart the game and play again then I get an error:
[image]

In Google Chrome console, the error occurs in the "`throw new RuntimeException(t)`" line of the javascript.  I'm less familiar with Javascript.  Has anyone encountered a similar issue before with Animation Scheduler?

```js
AnimationScheduler.get().requestAnimationFrame(new AnimationCallback() {
   @Override
   public void execute (double timestamp) {
    try {
     mainLoop();
    } catch (Throwable t) {
     error("GwtApplication", "exception: " + t.getMessage(), t);
     throw new RuntimeException(t);
    }
    AnimationScheduler.get().requestAnimationFrame(this, graphics.canvas);
   }
  }, graphics.canvas);
 }
```

In my Libgdx core code, the following lines code is called when the bird crashes and the game is over, so this is likely where the error is occurring:

```
 Gdx.app.postRunnable(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Sounds.gameOverSound.play(SettingsManager.gameVolume);
                highScore.stopCounting();
                for (Dodgeable dodgeable : dodgeables.activeDodgeables) {
                    dodgeable.reset();
                }
                dodgeables.resetSpawnTimes();
                for (Sound sound : Sounds.activeSounds){
                    //Stop all sounds currently playing
                    sound.stop();
                    Sounds.activeSounds.remove(sound);
                }
                //Reset all notifications that are active so they stop displaying
                Notifications.ExclamationMark.resetNotifications();
                Array<Body> bodies = new Array<Body>();
                world.getBodies(bodies);
                for (int i = 0; i < bodies.size; i++) {
                    world.destroyBody(bodies.get(i));
                }
                dispose();
                game.setScreen(new GameOverScreen(game, playServices, databaseAndPreferenceManager, highScore));
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved it... turns out, in my "dispose()" method, I was disposing of a Sound from another class and not recreating the Sound.  Therefore, I was disposing of a null sound which was causing the error.